# how to redirect php to html with hyphen in url

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my url that contain underscore with *`php`* extension like 
`app_development_company.php` to `app-development-company.html` in *`.htaccess`* file.

have a look at my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.js) gzip.php?type=js&file=$1
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.css) gzip.php?type=css&file=$1
    #RewriteBase   /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    #RewriteRule    ^index\.html$       index.php   [L]
    RewriteRule    ^/$      index.php   [L]
    RewriteRule    ^iphone-app-development\.html$       iphone_development.php  [L]
    RewriteRule    ^mobile-app-development-jaipur\.html$    mobile-app-development-jaipur.php   [L]
    RewriteRule    ^android-app-development\.html$      android_app_development.php     [L]

    RewriteRule    ^404\.html$      404.php     [L]
    ErrorDocument  404 https://wedigtech.com/404.html
</IfModule>
```

please help me to out this problem.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: So you want to rewrite any `/foo-bar-baz-abcd.html` to `/foo_bar_baz_abcd.php`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule index\.html index.php [NC,R]
```

Also Refer below link

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-redirect-indexhtml-to-indexphp/